# Sometimes my JUnit test fails and it doesn't should

Tags: java, junit

I'm starting to learn Java for myself and I follows a FFC tutorial, well, when I run my JUnit test it should return me always the objets number I just created (3), decrease or increase relatively when I comment or add any other object.

Here's my code

```
package testjunit;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PersonTest {

    @Test
    public void should_return_NumberofPersons() {
        Person Carlos = new Person();
        Person Rodolfo = new Person();
        Person Maria = new Person();

        assertEquals(3,Maria.numberOfPersons());
        // Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't ????
    }
    
}
```

and

```
package testjunit;

public class Person {

    private static int PersonCounter;
    public Person() {
        PersonCounter += 1;
        // Constructor
    }

    public int numberOfPersons() {
        return PersonCounter;
    }

}
```

Three runs and just one worked (look at the images)

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA7mB.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/SepVh.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5rhS.png

Each time it seems to return a different value,

> Message: N/A Stack trace: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but
> was:<5>

Thx,

Comment: Are there other tests in the actual PersonTest class?

Comment: The exact code you wrote here passes every time for me, as it should. Is there something missing? Have you been halting on a break-point with a debugger and inspecting some parts of your code that could have called `new Person()` additional times?

Comment: Oh! yes, there are, and I was not taking them into account, now the test always passes :) Thanks you two guys @julien.giband,@vsfDawg